# Java SE generate words from given Input

Tags: java, generator

I'm currently trying to generate *valid* words from a given Input.

Here is my pseudocode:

```
1. String and depth as a parameter for method.
2. Find similar or alike words from the same "wordfamily"
2b. You can specify the "depth". (Explained below)
3. return all found words as a List.
```

**I am not looking for the code, more like the approach or if there is a library or any specific topic I should do some research on**

*Here is a Testcase:*

The parameter is `Summer` and Depth `1`, a possible result may be `[Summer, Birds, Sun, Flowers, Warm ...]` (Let's say these are "direct" hits.)

Depending on the depth you get a more "abstract", more "abroad" not directly, but in a certain way assocating results with the given word.

Given the same Parameter `Summer`, but with a higher depth(`2`), you may now get in addition `[Winter, Snow ...]`

So the depth somehow influences on how many results you may get back.

Comment: This is really interesting but also a little too broad. Also, your pseudocode seems more like a requirements list.

Comment: How can I clearify? Any Idea where I should do some research?
You may be right with the "requirements list", but I don't expect YOU to solve it for me. Just give me a hint for a direction. @isaac

Comment: It sounds like this is a custom mapping, entering everything manually.  If you're trying to make this more programmatic you could convert depth so that depth 1 `summer -> birds, sun, flowers`, depth 2 would expand upon that list with `summer -> (birds -> sky, nest, flight), (sun -> bright, sky, burn), (flowers -> sun, color, pretty)`.  It would still require some manual data entry, but only for the top set, and not for subsequent depths.  If this is what you're trying to do, it'd be similar to markov chains

Comment: @0x45, when I say it's too broad, I mean you could do anything from a Web application using an external API, to a simple console application using a library, to even, heck, neural networks. As it is, your question is, as you said, too "abstract".

Comment: @phflack I'll have a look at markov chains. And yes, you "depth" understanding brings it on the point.